# Returning 64 bit negative number IA32 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Im learning IA32 bit assembly in a college course and im struggling to return a 64 bit number. I have to do (var8+var16)-(var32+var32x), and display the result in a 64 bit int. I get the right result, but the number should be negative. Can you look at this and give me some insight on what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Heres my code:

function.h:

```
long function(void);
```

function.s:

```
.section .data
.global var8
.global var16
.global var32
.global varx32
.global res
.section .text
.global function

function:

movl $0, %eax
movl $0, %edx   

movl var32, %eax
movl varx32, %edx

addl %edx, %eax


movl $0, %ebx
movw var16, %bx

movl $0, %ecx
movb var8, %cl

addl %ebx, %ecx

sbb %ecx, %eax



movl %eax, res  



ret
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"
char var8= 127;
short var16=32767; 
int var32=2147483647, varx32=2147483647;
long long res=0;


int main(void) {
printf("Value A: %d\nValue B: %d\nValue C: %d\nValue D: %d\n", var8, var16, var32, varx32);
function();

printf("\n%lld\n", res);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long function(void);` ... surely you meant `long long`

Comment: You only seem to be computing and storing back the least-significant 32 bits of the result, you'll need to keep track of the upper 32-bits separately as well by judicious use of carry. There is a curious subtraction with borrow but into the least-significant word, and from a sub-computation which can't overflow. Oh, and while it's not a problem for your particular values your inputs variables are signed yet your code treats them as unsigned which may fail for negative values.

Comment: @Jester: The function return value seems to be a decoy here..

Comment: @doynax oh, what a mess.

Comment: @Jester. Indeed. Also, the callee-saved `EBX` register isn't preserved.

Comment: Come on guys. I know it's a mess, it's my first week doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the sign bit. Right now you can only calculate with positive numbers. The result of the terms can overflow the 32-bit registers, if you handle with negative values. So store this result in two 32-bit registers.

`res` is a 64-bit variable (long long), that are 8 bytes. You store `%eax` to `res` - only 4 bytes. The upper 4 bytes stay on null (`long long res=0;`). So the result will be always positive, because the sign bit (the most-upper bit of the most-upper byte) is null.

TL;DR - try to understand the following function:

```
function:

    pushl %ebx                  # to be preserved by the callee (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl)        

    movswl var16, %eax          # = `movsx eax, var16` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html)
    movsbl var8, %edx           # = `movsx edx, var8` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html)
    addl %edx, %eax
    movl $0, %edx
    adcl $0, %edx               # EDX:EAX Result of first term

    movl var32, %ebx
    addl varx32, %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx
    adcl $0, %ecx               # ECX:EBX Result of second term

    subl %ebx, %eax             # EDX:EAX = EDX:EAX - ECX:EBX
    sbbl %ecx, %edx

    movl %eax, res              # Store EDX:EAX to `res`
    movl %edx, res + 4

    popl %ebx                   # return EBX unchanged
    ret
```

I changed the order of calculation and the used registers. By convention the return value of a function is stored in `EAX` (32 bit) or `EDX:EAX` (64 bit). If you decide to change the return type of `function` from `long` (32 bit in a 32 bit environment) to `long long` (64 bit), then you can also use the return value of my function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got a doubt about the movswl, are you using it because var16 is signed or is it because you are allocating it to eax?Does the movw only work for unsigned ?

Comment: @NunoOliveira: Yes, it expands var16 *signed* to EAX. For unsigned values >= 0x8000 you can use `movzwl ...` = `xorl %eax,%eax`& `movw var16, %ax` (as you did). But then you should correct the declarations in the C program.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, all your answers helped me alot. And thank you for taking the time for commenting the code. All the best to you.